# Eloquent Javascript: Is my solution too much or is it just as "allowable' as the author's?

Tags: javascript

I am going through Eloquent Javascript (Chapter 4, Exercise 2: Reversing an Array) and have only been learning Javascript for couple weeks. You have to recreate the reverse method for arrays. Am I working at this problem the wrong way? My code works, is that what matters most? Here is my code:

```
reverseArrayInPlace(arr) {
  var arrLength = arr.length;
  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arr.push(arr[i]);
  }
  arr.splice(0, arrLength);
  return arr;
}
```

This is the answer the author wrote:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    var old = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `newArray`? Not sure this is on topic here.

Comment: Ahhh oops, the first part of the exercise was a reverse method that sent it to a new array instead of modifying the original. I copy and pasted the first to the second then worked on it from there. I forgot to delete that. Thanks!

Comment: Your code does not really reverse the elements of the array in place.  Instead it is adding elements to the end of the array, and then removing the original elements, so the array length will grow to 2 times the original length of the array before the original elements are removed.  That could be an issue for very large arrays.  The author's version never grows larger than the original length of the array, since he is swapping the elements in place.

Comment: Yes thanks, I didn't fully understand what the author meant by in place at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the exerciser in the book, but in order to reverse an array in JavaScript you could simply use its native function `Array.prototype.reverse()`.

[More info can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse?v=control).

```js
let data = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
data.reverse();
console.log(data);
```

Regarding your algorithm it is different from the author one because the author swap array item in place.

---

Just for fun, I add my own implementation, I tried to make the code more easy to read using the same principal as the author of the book, I hope could be of interest:

```js
let data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

let revert = data => {
    let mid = Math.floor(data.length / 2);
    let left = 0;
    let right = data.length - 1;
    for(; left < mid; left++, right--){
      let temp = data[left];
      data[left] = data[right];
      data[right] = temp;
    }
  return data;     
};

let result = revert(data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I know this. The exercise was to create your own function to replicate it.

Comment: @graeme ahaha ok.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Helps with understanding. I did have to look up the difference between var and let and what I now know as arrow functions (=>) (like I said, I just started learning).

Comment: @graeme you are welcome :). Regarding var/let the only difference is that var gets scoped to the current function (Hoisting), while let gets scoped to the current block similar to other programming languages. If you found my answer useful, please do not to forget to accept it or upvote it :) Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is slower then author's because you're appending reverted array to array given as argument and then slicing array and returning other half. You iterate through whole array.

On the other hand author uses different algorithm. His idea is to swap elements in place, without array extension. He simply swaps first and last element, then second and second from the end, etc.

Therefore I'd go with authors solution because it's faster and doesn't use extra memory.

Comment: I may misunderstand you, but I am not actually iterating through a longer array than the original I don't think. It only iterates through the original array while adding it to itself to the front, and then splices out the original front half (doesn't iterate through it to perform this, or does it?).

Comment: your solution has `arr.lenght` iterations (for loop). In each iteration you add another element to the array. After for loop is finished you remove first `arr.lenght` elements. While removing those items you go through first `arr.lenght` elements once more, so you go through array twice. While author iterates only through `arr.lenght / 2` elements.

Comment: Ok Thanks, so array.splice() uses iteration (what I would assume anyways). Yes I agree that the author's method uses less iteration. I will try to keep efficiency in mind more.